# How to use class based view in Django for html button?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, button, methods

I wrote the following view:

```
class UserDeleteView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "user/user_delete.html"
    form_class = UserDeleteForm
    model = User

    def delete_my_account(self):
        user = get_user(self.request).user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            logout(self.request)
            user.delete()
            return redirect('/')
```

1) How can I call that method in `user/user_delete.html` ?

I think that my form_class attribute is not necessary since I use a `TemplateView`.

2) How would the code look like to use the `UserDeleteView` for `forms.py`? How to create the Delete Button?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the answer you are looking for, but you can use DeleteView instead of TemplateView which just needs a success url.

You can look its default functions methods that can be used here : [DeleteView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/)

And Documentation here: [Django Documentation on DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)

```
class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):

    template_name = "user/user_delete.html"
    form_class = UserDeleteForm
    model = User

    def get_success_url(self):
        # logout(self.request)
        return redirect('/')
```

Not sure if this would work in case of deleting the logged in user. I apologize as i could have mentioned this briefly without giving code in a comment, but i don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Instead of checking user.is_authenticated() LoginRequiredMixin can be used. Import it from django.contrib.auth.mixins and use it together with DeleteView like `class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):`

Comment: @user2853437 Check this out: [sfm-ui](https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-ui/tree/t28-structure_settings_file/sfm/ui). This branch has basic skeletal structure on how to use class based views. This is something i initially created when i was learning. I hope its helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be something like this

```
class UserDeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, object_id, *args, **kwargs):
        '''retrieve the object for the given object_id and delete it'''
        return redirect(url_to_be_redirected_to)
```

This should be sufficient for a basic Django view. In your HTML template lets say you have a button for deleting the object and lets also say that it has `id` attribute set to `deleteButton`. You will have to make use of javascripting to initiate the delete. For eg, your button is like

```
<a href="delete_url" id="deleteButton">Delete</a>
```

So you can write something like this

```
$("body").on("click", "a#deleteButton", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var csrf = fetch_csrf_value_and_assign_here;
    $.post(url, {csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf}, function(response){});
});
```

**PS:** This is a bare minimum way to do something you want. Also, it is not the only way. But this should give you another perspective to look at what you want to achieve.

**Edit 1:**
A sample url config for the view I have presented.

```
    url(r'delete/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',
          views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-user')
```

Then in your HTML, you can button like,

```
<a href="{% url 'appname:delete-user' object_id_you_want_to_delete %}" id="deleteButton">Delete</a>
```

You need to have `id` of the object you wish to delete in your template, which I am sure you do.

Comment: Could you provide another soultion without using javascript. For sure javascript is appreciated but i'd like to keep it flat.

Comment: If you take out the javascript from my code and still use the code I provided it will work. In that case, the request will be a simple non ajax request thats it.

Comment: It is still not that obvious to me. What's saved in request? - With your code it is a 'GET'? What's saved in object_id? Do you say, if i request the html-'id' in my View, like if object_id=='deleteButton' than proceed function? I still don't understand how to call that method "delete_my_account()" from html

Comment: @user2853437 I have just made an edit section to my answer. I have given a sample url config for the view. As you can see that `object_id` is passed via url. So you dont have to worry about GET/POST params. There is no need for any comparison against any html identifier. Just search for how to use reverse urls in HTML.